# Sum column based on condition based on corresponding column in excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2010, excel-2007

There are two column

A     B
1     1

2     1

3     3

Now I want to sum column A if A-(B+C) is equal to 0.

so for above example sum would be 1+3 = 4

Comment: Please edit your question. You have to correct most of the sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust ranges as necessary:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3=B1:B3)*A1:A3)
```

Comment: HI thank you so much it answers me perfect. But i have changed my question little. can you please help me out

Comment: @SainishMomin You cannot appreciably change your question and expect various different answers. Please, revert your post to its original version and accept rwilson's answer. To ask something else, just post a new question.